# How many bits does a digit have? (when the base is not known)

Tags: number-theory

If you see '0' or '12', but you don't know if it's a part of a binary or decimal or hexadecimal. Would it have the same number of bits?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the base, you don't know the number.  The string "12" is a representation of a number.  If you don't know the base, you can't parse the string into a number.

Answer (score 0):

No, $12_3=5_{10}=101_2$ has three bits.  $12_{16}=18_{10}=10010_2$ has five bits.

Comment: but then I could save more and more information in the same space. Just imagine I chose an even higher base, these 12 would include even more information. Shouldn't I then always take the biggest possible base, to save space?

Comment: A base can be any arbitrary positive integer so there is no "biggest possible base".

Comment: For any base $b$, $12_b=b+2$   Yes, with higher bases you can store more information in fewer digits.  Base $16$ takes only $\frac 14$ as many digits as bits in base $2$.  But you need to be able to store $16$ different digits, which (if you use binary) takes four bits each.  You are back where you started.  If you have a storage technology that can store sixteen different levels in one location, you can decrease the number of locations by a factor $4$ compared with binary.

Answer (score 0):

The number of bits a given number has depends on the number of places it occupies, and the implementation of the places.

The number $1,2$ has two places, so it would be represented as $[1][2]$, in its simplest form.

The number of bits per place depend on the representation used.  For example, in base 120, one can either represent the number as a straight binary number $119 = 1110111_2 $, or one can represent it in the usual way it is written, with a high place of 12, and a low place of 10 (ie $ 119 = 11,9 = 1011,1001_2 $.

It gets worse with bases like $60$, where one could use 6 bits (raw binary), or 7 bits (minimum to hold 6, 10), or 8 bits (supposing each column is 10).

One then also needs to consider the totality of the thing: are fractions and negative numbers to be held in the registers, is there room for exponents etc.

When the base is unknown or unusual, it is usual to hold the digits in an array, so $n(0)=2$, $n(1)=2$.  The size of the bits needed then includes the size of the separator in the array.